# Load dynamic controls using Xamarin MVVM

Tags: xaml, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am developing an application in Xamarin Forms using MVVM where I have this JSON:

```
[{
    type: 'text',
    title: 'Name'
    value: 'John',
    width: 50
},
{
    type: 'radio'
    Source: ['Male', 'Female']
    value: 'Male',
    width: 100
},
{
    type: 'checkbox'
    title: 'Married'
    value: false,
    width: 100
}]
```

Based on this JSON, I want to load controls (TextBox, RadioButton, and CheckBox in this example). I tried to find a solution but I couldn't get succeed.

This is a dynamic JSON retrieved from the database. It could be with different controls also. 
Is there a way to implement this?

Comment: Yes, of course.  What have you tried?

Comment: @Jason : I haven't tried. I am completely blank since I am a newbie in Xamarin. I tried to find out the solution in google but could not find it.

Comment: Are you already able to get that JSON from your App? Then start writing the code to populate the Xamarin controls based on your JSON data. Begin to create C# Class to deserialize that json as object. Then manipulate!
You have to create conventions and generate that json, use same convention in your code to manipulate the UI/validation/other logics out of it

Comment: @NirmalSubedi : I am able to get JSON. But I dont know how to Populate xamarin controls dynamically using MVVM framework ?

Comment: @confusedDeveloper You can't just add controls in your UI from your Basic ViewModel. You need to access the Page/Container/Control wherever you have to add those controls. That can be accessed in many ways, it's all depends on whatever setup you want/have in your project.

Answer (score 2):

Hi @confusedDeveloper,

Jason's answer works well while not considering MVVM pattern. However with MVVM it needs a little more code.

Dynamically changing of a view's content can be achieved in MVVM pattern by simply creating a view component deriving from ContentView with a BindableProperty and handling the changes to the bindable property.

Here I have created a View component ChangingView

1. In Xaml of the View Component assign a content view to the ComponentView

   ```
   <ContentView.Content>
   <ContentView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="mainView">
           <ContentView.Content>
               <Label BackgroundColor="Gray" Text="Placeholder"/>
           </ContentView.Content>
   </ContentView>
   </ContentView.Content>
   ```
2. In the Xaml.cs of the ComponentView create BindableProperty and handle its changes.

   ```
   // Fetch the required parameter from JSON and bind it to this property
   public string ViewType
   {
       get { return (string)GetValue(ViewTypeProperty); }
       set
       {
           SetValue(ViewTypeProperty, value);
       }
   }

   //Notice the OnViewChanged method subscription
   public static readonly BindableProperty ViewTypeProperty = BindableProperty.Create("ViewType", typeof(string), typeof(ChangingView), "placeholder", BindingMode.Default, null, OnViewChanged);
   ```

This static method is call a method similar to code in @Jason's answer

```
private static void OnViewChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newValue)
    {
        var viewControl = (bindable as ChangingView);
        if (viewControl != null)
        {
            viewControl.ChangeView((string)newValue);
        }
    }


private void ChangeView(string viewType)
    {
        if(viewType == "Button")
        {
            this.mainView.Content = new Button()
            {
                BackgroundColor= Color.Red,
                Text = "Button"
            };
        }
        else if(viewType == "Label")
        {
            this.mainView.Content = new Label()
            {
                BackgroundColor= Color.Green,
                Text = "Label"
            };
        }
    }
```

3. Finally use the component in Xaml of the Page where you require this ChangingView, The `DisplayControl` is the string derived from the required JSON parameter (Done in ViewModel, I leave this up to you).

   ```
   <component:ChangingView ViewType="{Binding DisplayControl}"/>
   ```

Hope it fits your scenario. Comment if further information is required.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

there are lots of ways to tackle this - one approach would be to do something like this

```
foreach(var c in json)
{
  switch(c.type) {
    case "text":
      var c = new Entry() { ... };
      myLayout.Children.Add(c);
      break;
    case "checkbox":
      var c = new Checkbox() { ... };
      myLayout.Children.Add(c);
      break; 
    case ...
  }
}
```

Comment: How would you bind this to a ObservableCollection?